# Spring Boot Rest Web Service fetching multiple parameters in Get Request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, web-services, rest-assured

I am creating Spring Boot Web service and I have a Model Employee

```
public class Employee {
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String designation;
  private int salary;
 //Has Getters and Setters
}
```

I want to create a Get request which will fetching and filter the List of Employees based on the parameters given by user.

For example, if the user gives name of an employee and designation of employee, the get method should filter those result. For various combination of parameters it should work.

```
@Override
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        if (parameters.size() == 0)
//          code to return all employees;
        List<Employee> selectedEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        for(Employee currentEmployee: new ArrayList<Employee>(employee.values())) {
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> check: parameters.entrySet()) {
                try {
                    if(check.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
                        int condition = (int) Employee.class.getMethod("get" + check.getKey()).invoke(currentEmployee);
                        if((int) check.getValue() == condition)
                            selectedEmployees.add(currentEmployee);
                    } else if (check.getValue() instanceof String) {
                        String condition = (String) Employee.class.getMethod("get" + check.getKey()).invoke(currentEmployee);
                        if (((String) check.getValue()).equals(condition))
                            selectedEmployees.add(currentEmployee);
                    }
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return selectedEmployees; 
    }
```

In order to avoid multiple if else cases I am filtering list based on String and Integer above.

I think I am making an error in the below code which sending request in Controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/employees","/{id}/{name}/{designation}/{salary}"})
    public List<Employee> getEmployeeByProperty(EmployeeRequestParameters requestParams){
        //Map for storing parameters to filter the List
        Map<String, Object> filterParams = new HashMap<>();
        if(requestParams.getIdParam().isEmpty()) {
            filterParams.put("id", Integer.parseInt(requestParams.getIdParam()));   
        } 
        if(!requestParams.getNameParam().isEmpty()) {
            filterParams.put("name", requestParams.getNameParam()); 
        } 
        if(!requestParams.getDesignationParam().isEmpty()) {
            filterParams.put("designation", requestParams.getDesignationParam());   
        } 
        if(requestParams.getSalaryParam().isEmpty()) {
            filterParams.put("salary", Integer.parseInt(requestParams.getSalaryParam()));   
        }       
        return EmployeeService.getEmployeesByProperty(filterParams);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If {id} field is not full, {name} or {designation} or {salary} to be null.For {name} or {designation} or {salary} to be full Because should be {id} full.

```
@GetMapping("/employees")
public List<Employee> getEmployeeByProperty(@RequestParam(value = "id", required=false) String id,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "name", required=false) String name,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "designation", required=false) String designation,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "salary", required=false) int salary) {
                                                //Your codes
                                            }
```

Even if {id} is empty, you can use others.